# throw Exception in create new object from Stage class in javafx

Tags: java, exception, javafx, instance, stage

I have MyStage class extended from Stage class

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyStage extends Stage{
    // cod ...
}
```

I want create new instans from MyStage class

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyStage ms = new MyStage();
   ms.show();
}
```

}

But it gives the following error

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1209)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:239)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
    at test.MyStage.<init>(MyStage.java:6)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:285)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:674)
    at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:79)
    ... 5 more
C:\Users\sherkat\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

please help me thanks

Comment: 1. Don't subclass `Stage`. 2. You need to use the normal application startup; i.e. subclass `Application` and us the `Stage` passed into your `start()` method. Read the [`Application` Javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) (or pretty much any intro tutorial).

Comment: As alternative to James's suggestion there's `Platform.startup`, but that makes terminating the app a bit trickier. The preferred way indeed is subclassing and launching `Application`.